# Not able to install MySQL server on CentOS 6.6

Tags: linux, mysql, centos6, yum

I tried this following command

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# rpm -qa | grep mysql  
mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64  
mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch  
[root@n yum.repos.d]#
```

But I give followed command

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# yum remove mysql   
Setting up Remove Process   
No Match for argument: mysql       
Package(s) mysql available, but not installed.      
No Packages marked for removal        
[root@n yum.repos.d]#
```

I tried to install mysql  but it showing following error

```
[root@n yum.repos.d]# rpm -ivh http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm   
Retrieving http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm  
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]  
        package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch (which is newer than   mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch) is already installed  
        file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql from install of mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch    
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community-source.repo from install of mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch     
        file /etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-community.repo from install of mysql- community-release-el5-5.noarch conflicts with file from package mysql- community-release-fc21-5.noarch 

[root@n yum.repos.d]# dir  
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Vault.repo  
CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  epel.repo  
CentOS-fasttrack.repo  epel-testing.repo  
CentOS-Media.repo      mysql-community-release-el6-5.noarch.rpm  
[root@n yum.repos.d]#
```

Can any one help to solve this problem ?

Comment: How about `yum remove mysql-community-release`?

Comment: It seems you've a Fedora Core package installed (fc21-5) rather than the Enterprise Linux version. Did you follow a guide which had you install via rpm?

Comment: Why do you have packages for EL5 and FC21 in an EL6 server?

Instal EL6 rpm packages!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have installed `mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch` in the first place.  That RPM is clearly labelled that it's for fedora core 21.

`yum erase mysql-community-release-fc21-5.noarch`.

Next you're trying to install `mysql-community-release-el5-5.noarch.rpm`.  Do that and you're back to where you started, with a slightly different error message.  That RPM is clearly labelled that it's for el5 (CentOS 5.x RHEL 5.x).

As the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html) clearly says, you need to download the one marked el6.

```
For an EL6-based system, the command is in the form of:

shell> sudo yum localinstall mysql-community-release-el6-{version-number}.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks Yoonix, I coluld solve the problem by using these way and intalled the MySQL Community Server 5.6.24 successfully.